# Amazon S3: upload duplicate files with different keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

If I upload the same files twice with different keys, will the storage be twice?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. keys are nothing but the path of your file on s3. So if you upload the same file twice with different keys, that file will be uploaded twice. So it is like I'm uploading test.jpg file, if first time key is "image/test.jpg" it will be saved in image folder. And on second time I'm uploading same file with key "data/test.jpg" then it will be saved in data folder.

Comment: Thank you. I think so after testing. Maybe S3 has some internal hash testing, however, from what I see, the storage becomes twice.